# How to receive response headers using $resourse

Tags: angularjs, authentication, header

I am trying to send and receive headers through $resourse

My code is shown below

From server side I sending header i.e. **auth** so I need to receive this header in front end... I am able to get this header by using $http. But I need it by using $resourse...

```
controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'services',
    function($scope, $location, services) {
        $scope.validateLogin = function() {

            services.getUserData().save($scope.user, function(data, status, headers, config) {
                localData.setData(data);
                $location.path("/home");
            }, function(error, status, headers, config) {
                alert(error.statusText);
            });
        };
    }
])
```

In my factory I have written code like

```
.factory('services', function($resource) {
  function createNewUser(){
    return $resource("/createUser");
  }
  function getUserData(){
    return $resource("/userLogin");
  }
  function getUserSticky(){
    return $resource("/userLogin");
  }
  return {
      createUser: createNewUser,
      getUserData:getUserData,
      getSavedSticky: getUserSticky
    };

})
```